# Show formatted Ajax JSON response in view Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'm receiving a JSON response with a list of objects (with id, name, etc) from this Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: _this.attr('action'),
  data: _this.serialize(),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(json_data) {
    alert('success!');
    alert(JSON.stringify(json_data));
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert('error!');
  }
});
```

Now I need to display this information in a view as a table, something like:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= "ID"
      %th= "Name" 
  %tbody
    - @response.each do |resp|
      %tr
        %td= resp.id
        %td= resp.name
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using jquery only, you can use something like that for success function:

```
function(json_data) {
  var $tbody = $('table tbody');
  $.each(json_data, function() {
    var $tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($tbody);
    $('<td></td>').text(this.id).appendTo($tr);
    $('<td></td>').text(this.name).appendTo($tr);
  })
}
```

However as your templates get increasingly difficult it might be worth looking into some client side templating solutions (for example [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)).

Comment: Worked! Sorry for the late response, the question is about a side project and I've been a little busy :)